# WP REST API Access-Control-Allow-Origin response is cached

Tags: plugins, plugin-json-api, wp-api

I have an AngularJS site that is pulling in posts from WordPress via the plugin "WP REST API (WP API)". I am testing a site on both dev and staging subdomains, and the WP API works on both. However, when I visit one domain, and then switch over to another domain immediately afterward, then the dynamically-generated Access-Control-Allow-Origin is "stuck" on the previous domain to make the API calls. It's not until I refresh the page, that the response header updates to the current domain making the request. Here is what it says in the Chrome console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://wp.domain.tld/wp-json/pages/couples.
>   The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'http://staging.domain.tld' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
>   Origin 'http://dev.domain.tld' is therefore not allowed access.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What auth are you using? Are you also using SSL? it appears not, but just checking.

Comment: have you got an answer?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue? I also have the same issue.

Comment: downvoted as it sounds like an angular/browser problem that is not specifically related to wordpress.

Comment: I'm seeing this also. I've also tried allowing both the initial (preview host) and the live host in allowed origins but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

This might be more of an AngularJS question.  You can try setting your headers to `no-cache`.  Something like:

```
var req = {
    headers : {
        "Pragma"        : "no-cache",
        "Expires"       : -1,
        "Cache-Control" : "no-cache"
    }
};
```